# How to dynamically add Item to QComboBox with QSqlQueryModel

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I am new to QT and learning how to populate QComboBox. I know about addItem() method of QComboBox to add new item. But in my case it is not working. Below is relevant part my code.

```
    QSqlQuery q;

    q.prepare("SELECT fname from Person");

    if(q.exec())
    {
        QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel(this);

        model->setQuery(q);

        ui->comboFName->setModel(model);

        db.close();
    }

    QString item = "XYZ";

    ui->comboFName->addItem(item);
```

My QComboBox is getting populated with data from QSqlQueryModel but manual insertion of    addItem() is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decide whether to use a model or the manual way to add items, since using both leads to a strange behaviour http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/15391-QComboBox-gt-setModel-gt-Strange-behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Once you set the model of UIComponent it becomes the source for items, it would be populated from this model.

QSqlQueryModel is read only so you can't modify it (class reference page http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsqlquerymodel.html).

You can't Add Items to this SQL result Model.

To Add your items you must clear (function clear()) the model, then use function AddItem.

Hope this would help.